# Detect virtualization in bash

Tags: bash, virtualization, kvm, xen, openvz

One of my commands in my bash script will depend on the virtualization of the server (XEN or OpenVZ or KVM ). How can I check which of these is in use in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a small shell script that is able to detect virtualization and it handles Xen,OpenVZ,KVM,Parallels, Vmware and many more

`virt-what`

Installation with yum is pretty straight forward

Here is the output on my system

```
$ virt-what
kvm
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a very useful script called `imvirt` that handles Xen, OpenVZ, VMware, VirtualBox, KVM, and lots of others. It's available as a package in Debian, or from the [imvirt web site](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html).

```
$ imvirt
Xen PV 4.1
```

Comment: @user2650277 - the web site mentions a stand-alone package, with all Perl dependencies included. That should run on CentOS.

Comment: I did `yum install imvirt`  and unfortunately the imvirt command show errors on my system.It seems unable to detect that i am on KVM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect host (dom0) for xen, check

```
[ "$(cat /proc/xen/capabilities)" == "control_d" ]
```

If you want to detect in VM,
You need to execute [`cpuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1%3a_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) instruction in VM, with original_eax=1.
If the resultant ecx has MSB set `((ecx & 0x80000000) != 0)`, then you are under VM.
This is assuming that your hypervisor supports [viridian interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Xen does.
`cpuid` package is easily available for many linux distros. I'm sure windows port would be available too. Else, the code is pretty simple for you to write...

Comment: So just to confirm, you want to detect if the dom0 is under `OpenVz`. Right?